# retrieving a file extensions

Tags: php, filenames, glob

I'm creating a website that has a huge number of folders. I want to use those pre existing files. But the previous webdesigner has been mixing .JPG and .jpg. Cleaning it up takes forever.

If I know if 'banner.jpg' exists, I know that the other files also have this file extension.

So I want to do something like this:

```
foreach(glob($FolderName.'/*') as $file) {
                    if  (stripos($file,$FolderName.'/banner.jpg') === false ) 
                         { $Extension=".JPG"; }
                    else { $Extension=".jpg"; }
                    }
```

But: no matter what, $Extension is always ".JPG".

Comment: You're using [stripos](http://docs.php.net/stripos): "Find the position of the first occurrence of a _case-insensitive_ substring in a string"

Comment: Would it no be easier to use a tool like `awk` or `sed` to do something like this?

Comment: as VolkerK said, `stripos` cannot make a difference between jpg and JPG. Try using `strpos` instead.

Comment: Can you show us the output (files list)?

Comment: btw, try `' '.$file,$FolderName.'/banner.jpg'` instead of just $file in `stripos`

Comment: I'm very sorry for the late response! I thought that I would receive an email when someone responded to this question. Meanwhile I solved the problem:

`$filename = $FolderNaam.'/banner.JPG';
if (file_exists($filename)) { $Extension=".JPG";} 
else { $Extension=".jpg";}`